# Tool or command to track Java class utilization in multiple JARs?

Tags: java, xml, grep, classpath, dependency-graph

I have some very serious JAR hell going on, and need to scan my entire Java classpath (consisting of more than 50 JARs) for all the instances where a particular class is used, let's call it `com.fizz.buzz.Widget`.

**This `Widget` class could be referenced both from inside bytecode (.class files) as well as XML descriptor files inside the JARs.** I imagine I would need a 2-pronged approach: 1 phase where I essentially `zgrep` through all the JARs, scanning for XML files containing `com.fizz.buzz.Widget` in them, and a 2nd phase where I somehow scan the bytecode. Either way, not entirely sure what I need to do for both phases, or if there is a magical tool that does this for me all in one fell swoop. Ideas?

Comment: There are many tools that will find references in code. Unless it's a known XML format you'll likely need to roll that one yourself. As long as you're sure there's nothing else instantiating/referencing the classes (e.g., reflection) that should be sufficient. It's actually pretty easy to walk bytecode using any of the several tools available, though.

Comment: Take a look at CodePro Analytix: https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/?csw=1  I don't know if it searches the XML files or not though.

Comment: Thanks, you made me love Visual Studio even more. +1